# How do I upgrade GIT for Intellij?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Title says it all.  Is there some widget that does this for me or is a just a jar replace.  If the later, how do I find the jars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just tried a normal GIT upgrade starting here:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/installing-and-upgrading-git-776640906.html

I downloaded the installer and ran it.  I am on Windows 10 so I just took the defaults (except for the text editor).

Intellij picked it up with no problems. Someone else on my team got an error about not having admin rights.  It is probably best to run the installer with admin rights.

The skinny I guess is:  Intellij does not "manage" GIT.  It just uses the one installed on your system.

Answer (score 2):

When I use the Git plugin with IntelliJ, I just point it to the actual running version of Git which I have on my machine.  So if you want to use an upgraded version of Git, then you should download and install it first.  After doing that, if you visit Project Settings from the drop down menu (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> on Windows machines), you can navigate to the settings for version control.  Here is screen capture from my MacBook Air:

[image: screen capture]

Point IntelliJ to the local location of the upgraded version of Git, and the plugin should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a local path to Git:
*My Intellij is 2019*

> Settings -> Version Control -> Git -> *Path to Git executable.*

Comment: Well, I have that.  Its all set up.  Just need to upgrade.

Comment: Well upgrade / download new version locally and point to it ?

Comment: Did you do it ?

Comment: Yea, see above.